Neo4j: how to pass parameters to relationships?
The official website of neo4j point out that we can not pass parameters to the type of relationships.
However, I need to pass parameters to relationships when adding embeddings in batch.
Neo4j adds batch vectors for nodes by
    driver.execute_query('''
    UNWIND $movies as movie
    MATCH (m:Movie {title: movie.title, plot: movie.plot})
    CALL db.create.setNodeVectorProperty(m, 'embedding', movie.embedding)
    ''', movies=nodes_with_embeddings, database_=DB_NAME)

add embedding property for nodes
This code use $movies to pass parameters and pass movie.title as property value. Each movie is a dict.
However, I can not pass relationship types with $datas like MATCH (h:Entity {id: data.id})-[r: data.r]->(t:Entity {id: data.id})
I've tried to use common concatenation for strings to pass parameters, and add embedding property one by one.
For example, "MATCH (h:Entity {id: data.h_id})-[r:"+data['r']+"]->(t:Entity {id: data.t_id})
However, I want to use batch operation to speed up.
Is there a way to pass parameters to the relationships for batch operation?
Thanks for your time.

You can use the APOC procedure apoc.create.relationship to create relationships with dynamic types. For example:
UNWIND $data AS d
MATCH (h:Entity {id: d.h_id})
MATCH (t:Entity {id: d.t_id})
CALL apoc.create.relationship(h, d.r, NULL, t) YIELD rel
RETURN rel


That works. Thanks a lot!

You can have the value which you need to use for relationship condition in the same parameter and use in the query. For example
To set the parameters run the below query
:params {data:[{id:12312,relId:123}]}

Then run the below query to filter the relationship using params
UNWIND $data as d MATCH (e:Entity{id:d.id})-[r:hasData{id:d.relId}]->(e1:Entity) return *

